# n sets such that any x belongs to at least k implies that at least one set has measure at least k/n

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Let $k, n \in \mathbb{N}: k ≤ n$ and let $E_1, \dots , E_n \subseteq [0, 1]: ((\forall i, E_i$ is Lebesgue measurable subset$)$ & $( x \in [0, 1] \Rightarrow |\{E_i: x \in E_i, i \leq n \}| \geq k))$; (that is: $x$ belongs to at least $k$ of the sets $E_1,\dots,E_n $).

Show that there exists $1 ≤ i_0 ≤ n: λ(E_{i_0}) \geq k/n$.

I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{E_{i}}\geq k1_{[0,1]}$ so taking the integral on both sides we find by linearity of integrals: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda (E_{i}) \geq k$$

Comment: So, if I assume that, $\forall i \in \{1,\dots, n \}, λ(E_i) < k/n$, then their sum will be less than $k$, which is a contradiction. Thus, at least one $E_i$ (denoted $E_{i_0}$) has measure that is not less than $k/n$. Nice! Thanks!